# Delete issues with duplicate title (or change their State)

Tags: javascript, youtrack

I created a new mailbox integration that is creating new issues in my project.
I'd like to avoid duplicate issues, something like:

```
rule Delete duplicate issues after being added automatically with a To check State

when State == {To check} {
 //check all issues in the Project
 //check if there is an issue with the same Title {
  State = Archived; // or delete the Issue
 }
}
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed that Youtrack automatically set a new issue with similar title and description as `related to` the existing one.
So I created a new rule

```
rule Delete duplicates in Board

when Stage == {To Check} && issue == relates to {
 applyCommand("delete");
}
```